# Issue with datatypes for np.integrate.quad

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a basic integral with np.integrate.quad function.

```
print(type(num1))
print(type(num2))
print(type(lower_limit))
phi_1 = sp.integrate.quad(integrand, lower_limit, num1)
phi_2 = sp.integrate.quad(integrand, lower_limit, num2)

<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
<class 'float'>
```

I'm getting this error,

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation for scipy.integrate.quad (at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) you will see that the third parameter should be of type float and is the upper limit of integration. Yours is a matrix, this is your problem.